# Idiomatic way to get from nested structures in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Which of these is more idiomatic Clojure?

```
(def book {:title "Joy of Clojure" 
           :authors ["Michael Fogus" "Chris Houser"]})

(get-in book [:authors 0])
;; => "Michael Fogus"

(-> book :authors first)
;; => "Michael Fogus"
```

When I have much more complicated data structures, this becomes more relevant.  Presumably there's no technical difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get-in` is better for nested structures, because many interesting keys are not callable, in particular indexes in a vector (other than `first` or `second`) or string keys in hash-maps.

```
user=> (get-in [{:a 0} 1 nil "unknown" {:b {"context info" 42}}] [4 :b "context info"])
42
```

Comment: also lets you specify a default value if the key isn't present

Comment: Also worth noting that `get-in` only works with associative structures, so if you have a seq in your map, you're better off with the threading macro